# Reduction of hypergeometric function for integer parameters

Tags: reference-request, hypergeometric-function

Consider integers $a,b,c,d>0$ and the hypergeometric function

$${}_3F_2(1-d,b,a+b;a+b+c,b+1;1)$$

I don't know much about hypergeometric functions but I understand that when the parameters are integer valued we get some simplification. Unfortunately, I can't seem to figure this out or find a good reference.

---

**My attempt**:

For $d=1$, the function evaluates to 1.

For $d=2$, we have

$$1-\frac{b(a+b)}{(b+1)(a+b+c)}$$

For $d=3$, we have

$$1-\frac{2b(a+b)}{(b+1)(a+b+c)} + \frac{b(a+b)(a+b+1)}{(b+2)(a+b+c)(a+b+c+1)}$$

For $d=4$, we have

$$1-\frac{3b(a+b)}{(b+1)(a+b+c)} + \frac{3b(a+b)(a+b+1)}{(b+2)(a+b+c)(a+b+c+1)} - \frac{b(a+b)(a+b+1)(a+b+2)}{(b+3)(a+b+c)(a+b+c+1)(a+b+c+2)}$$

I can begin to write out the expression for general integer $d\ge 1$ as

$$\sum_{k=0}^{d-1}(-1)^k\binom{d-1}{k}\cdots$$

I'm not sure how the rest proceeds.

Answer (score 1):

[Wolfram functions reference](http://functions.wolfram.com/) is a good place to find identities like this. [Here's the one for $\;_3F_2$](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric3F2/). For this, you probably want. Unfortunately I'm not finding much in [values at $z = 1$](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric3F2/03/02/), but there's a lot to go through.